# Integration involving fixed points

Tags: calculus, integration

A few days ago I ran into this statement

If $a$, $b$ are fixed points of a function $f$, then

$$\int_a^b(f(x) + f^{-1}(x)) \,\mathrm dx = b^2 - a^2.$$

I checked it for a few simple cases like $\int_0^1 (x^3 + x^{1/3}) \,\mathrm dx = 1/4+3/4=1 $ where $f(x) = x^3$.

I could only come up with a geometric justification for the above statement. Is there a analytic proof of the statement relying on only high school level calculus?

It is also possible that it is a well known theorem or the statement is wrong, but I can't come up with any counterexample.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: his is correct; yours is not.

Comment: More generally, I think a proof is possible with the use of integration of parts.

Comment: I think it is correct , integration of first term would be 1/4 and of second term would be 3/4  which gives 1 . Wolfram alpha gives the same result http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration+from+0+to+1+of+x%5E3+%2B+x%5E%281%2F3%29

Comment: Oh, extremely sorry, my mistake. Left out the $1/4$ of the first integration.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the theorem is true and the proof is very simple when $f$ is differentiable.

Let $$f^{-1}(x)=y$$ Then your integral becomes $$\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)+f^{-1}(x))dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}(y)f'(y)dy\\
=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+\int_{a}^{b}yf'
(y)dy=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+\left[yf(y)\right]_{a}^{b}-\int_{a}^{b}f(y)dy\\
=bf(b)-af(a)=b^2-a^2\hspace{8cm}\Box$$

Comment: You have assumed that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: yes, true That I have assumed.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a geometric (may be intuitive) answer.

Notice that if $f$ has fixed points $a$, $b$ then $f$ and $f^{-1}$ will meet at $(a.a)$ and $(b,b)$ points.

So $\int_a^b(f(x) + f^{-1}(x)) \,\mathrm dx=\text{area under}\ f+\text{area under}\ f^{-1}=2(\text{area under the line y=x}) = 2\int_a^bx \mathrm dx=b^2-a^2$

**Edit:**

Assume $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are monotone in $(a,b)$ (and Riemann-Stieltjes integrable). Then,

$$\displaystyle\int_a^bf^{-1}dx=\displaystyle\int_a^bxdf=\displaystyle\int_a^bfdf-\displaystyle\int_a^b(f-x)df=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}+\displaystyle\int_a^b(x-f)dx
=b^2-a^2-\displaystyle\int_a^bfdx$$.

Comment: I came up with the same geometric idea though I couldn't formalize it . Is there a way to make it rigorous ?

Comment: If you assume $f$ and its inverse are continuous may be, I can give you a better answer.

Comment: Assuming they are continuous , what approach would you use ?

Comment: I have edited accordingly. Hope that helps.

Comment: But since $f$ has two distinct fixed points, can it be monotone?

Comment: Why can't it be? I have said monotone in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Oh, Ok, i didn't notice that, sorry.